# Should we have different tags for new World of Darkness and old WoD?

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now there are two questions ([553](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/553) and [686](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/686)) on the site about new World of Darkness (typically abbreviated NWoD), and I'm writing up one related to old World of Darkness (OWoD). Should we differentiate questions about NWoD and OWoD with [nwod]/[new-world-of-darkness] and [owod]/[old-world-of-darkness] tags, or should we leave them all [wod]/[world-of-darkness]?

If we separate them into NWoD and OWoD, which one do [wod]/[world-of-darkness] become tag synonyms for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [World of Darkness tag synonyms](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139/world-of-darkness-tag-synonyms)

Comment: @Agent_9191 I disagree. I don't think you paid close enough attention to the specific focus of each question. This one deals only with old vs. new WoD tagging. The other deals only with deciding on the proper parent tag for the synonym system.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say separate tags -- the mechanics are noticeably different, certainly as different as AD&D 1st and 2nd edition mechanics. And the worlds are very different despite superficial similarities.

Comment: Agreed. But the biggest question is do enough people play oWoD to make the tag worthwhile?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Byrant.

Comment: Good point, Jeremiah. If we do separate them, that seems to imply that [wod]/[world-of-darkness] would be synonyms for [nwod]/[new-world-of-darkness]. Do you agree?

Comment: @Jeremiah: Decidedly so. The Old World has a strong, vital fanbase -- enough that White Wolf is releasing more products to appeal to them later this year.